# Unable to create a Jersey RESTful Service in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey, tomcat8

Im trying to create a RESTful Service on Eclipse using Jersey.

I repeatedly get the following error when I'm trying to run in localhost within Eclipse.

```
SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web application [/TestPrject] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
```

My web.xml looks something like this :

```
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
    version="3.1">
<display-name>TestPrject</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.eviac.blog.MyTestSvc</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have all the Jersey 2.0 jars under WEB-INF/lib as well. I'm running Apache Tomcat 8.0 with JDK 1.7.0_79 .

The Class used for Service entry is as follows:

```
@Path("/")
public class MyTestSvc {

    @GET
    @Path("/callService")
    @Produces({ "text/plain" })
    public String userName() {

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have [jersey-container-servlet-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core) dependency.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using maven, add the following dependency to your pom

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>{your version here (2.0)?}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Im not using Maven

Answer (score 0):

As per service class or controller your url seems to be like this

ProjName/rest//callService

So make in service class

```
@Path("/service")
public class MyTestSvc {

    @GET
    @Path("/callService")
    @Produces({ "text/plain" })
    public String userName() {

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Then url will be ProjName/rest/service/callService

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in your application:

### Fixing the dependencies

If you are using Maven, ensure you have the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If not, ensure you have all the [`jersey-container-servlet`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.2/jersey/project/jersey-container-servlet/dependencies.html) artifact dependencies on the classpath.

### Fixing the `web.xml`

The [`jersey.config.server.provider.packages`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#PROVIDER_PACKAGES) parameter defines one or more packages that contain application-specific resources and providers. Change:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.eviac.blog.MyTestSvc</param-value>
</init-param>
```

To:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.eviac.blog</param-value>
</init-param>
```

If you need to add more packages, use `;` or `,` to separate them.

Once Tomcat 8.x supports Servlet 3.x, you don't need a `web.xml` deployment descriptor for simple applications. For more details, check the [Jersey documentation regarding deployment in Servlet 3.x containers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#deployment.servlet.3).

### Improving the resource path design

Avoid [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotations with an empty string or just a slash as a value. It smells bad.

Comment: When I'm trying to add `ServletContainer` in code, Eclipse asks me to import from `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet`, it suggests that the reference to `jersey-container-servlet` is added, which is desired. However, it is in web.xml where I'm still facing the error.

Comment: FYI : Im not using Maven

Comment: @RitwikSen If you are creating an application for example purposes, it's a good opportunity to start using Maven.